# Task serialisation error on using UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I get Task serialisation error for the following

```
def md5(s: String) = {
MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(s.getBytes).map("%02X".format(_)).mkString
}
val md5UDF = udf(md5 _)

contents_stat
  .withColumn("id", md5UDF($"URL"))
```

I assume that the problem lies in `MessageDigest`. I can do `coalesce(1)` before `.withColumn("id", md5UDF($"URL"))`, but is there any other way to still do the operation on multiple machines?

Comment: Don't assume. Better include stack trace and / or MCVE.

Comment: Isn't there an inbuilt `md5` function in Spark?

Comment: @philantrovert: Yeah, indeed you are right. There is such function. Basically, I can simply do `contents_stat.withColumn("id", md5($"URL"))`.

Comment: @philantrovert, I guess you can answer it below so that the OP can accept it and it would be helpful for others as well